# Can't return value when getting 400 response in Meteor HTTP.post()

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I want to return a value from server side to client side, If I get error response from the API Call.

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.call 'foo',data,(err,results)->
    console.log(results)


if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.methods foo:(data)->
    results = Meteor HTTP.post "example.com",{
      data: data
    },(err,results)
    if err
      console.log('abc')
      return 0
```

If I get 400 error from example.com, then It is printing `abc` but it is not returning anything to the client.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your syntax is invalid, presumably you meant to put a `->` after the `HTTP.post`s `(err, results)` and then indent the next three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user3374348 stated, you should use HTTP.post *synchronously* if you want your method to return its results. Otherwise, `HTTP.post`'s *callback* will return the result (to nowhere), *not* your `foo` method. Here's how you would do it, in regular JavaScript:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    foo: function (data) {
      try {
        var result= HTTP.post("example.com", {
          data: data
        });
        return result;
      }
      catch (error) {
        // todo: check if the error is 400
        console.log("abc");
        return 0;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `HTTP.post` is a Meteor built-in, it already works synchronously on the server. You can still call it asynchronously by passing a callback though.

Comment: True, then it's even simpler.